# Checking wether a user typed in correct formatted time

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do one go about checking wether or not the user typed in a valid time like "hh:mm:ss" what ive tried is:

```
string format = "hh:mm:ss";
static bool ValidateTime(string time, string format)
        {
            DateTime outTime;
            return DateTime.TryParseExact(time, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outTime);
        }
```

then checking wether it returnes true or false:

```
 bool result = ValidateTime(redigerINDtextbox.Text, format);

        if (result)
        {
            redigerINDtextbox.Text = "yay";
        }
        else
            redigerINDtextbox.Text = "nay";
```

It always returns false, when parsing in "7:17:05" or even "14:23:23" for example.

Comment: Do you only need to check the formatting or will you need the (correctly converted to non-string type) result later? If the former, you might want to consider regex. If the latter, why are you throwing away the conversion result?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Why using regex when there is a method designed for this exact purpose? TryParseExact is perfectly fine

Comment: @KevinGosse - it's not "designed for this purpose". It does *more* than may be required here, it actually performs a conversion. If the OP requires the conversion, then, as I stated in the second part, I'd query why they're throwing that result away. If they don't require the conversion, I said they *might* want to consider a regex instead, since all they (apparently) want is to check how well a string conforms to a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hh` is for 12-hour clock, so "14:23:23" can't be parsed. For 24-hour clock, use `HH`:

```
string format = "HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: you're right, but dosnt fix the problem of it returning false tho. :-)

Comment: @MathiasRønnowNørtoft  Double-check your code, because it should return true: http://ideone.com/aO4fRa

Comment: actually it worked thanks, the problem was me having the time < 10 to be formatted as "h:mm:ss", switched the formatting and then i had forgot the !ispostback so it kept checking the wrong string. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `DateTime`

Try this

```
string format = "hh:mm:ss";
static bool ValidateTime(string time, string format)
{
TimeSpan times;
return TimeSpan.TryParseExact(time,
                                    format,
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                    out times);
}
```

Comment: Still only returns false, am i checking the result incorretly?